# What does the Facebook JS SDK parameter 'cookie' do?

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

What would setting the Facebook JS SDK parameter 'cookie' to false do? I've had an issue recently where cookies for too many apps on the same domain have caused Apache to give an error about headers being too large.

Answer (score 1):

From the facebook [javascript SDK documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) :

```
...
cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
...
```

As you can see - facebook uses cookies to save session information about logged in users.